# An advanced integral $\int_0^1 \frac{(2 e)^{-1/y} \left(2 e^{1/y}-e 2^{1/y}\right)}{1-y} \ dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to ask you how you would like to approach the integral below

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(2 e)^{-1/y} \left(2 e^{1/y}-e 2^{1/y}\right)}{1-y} \ dy$$

and then recommend me some tools you'd employ. It's hard to even imagine how to start here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach, giving your integral in terms of values of a special function.

By the change of variable $x=1/y$, you obtain
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{(2 e)^{-1/y} \left(2 e^{1/y}-e 2^{1/y}\right)}{1-y} {\rm d}y &=\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{(2 e)^{-x} \left(2 e^x-e 2^{x}\right)}{x-1} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x}\\\\
&=\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{2^{1-x} -e^{1-x}}{x-1} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x}\\\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2^{-u} -e^{-u}}{u} \frac{{\rm d}u}{u+1}\\\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty} \left(\int_{\ln 2}^{1}e^{-tu}{\rm d}t \right)\frac{{\rm d}u}{u+1}\\\\
&=\int_{\ln 2}^{1}\left(\int_0^{+\infty}  \frac{e^{-tu}}{u+1} du\right){\rm d}t\\\\
&=\int_{\ln 2}^{1} e^t \:\Gamma(0,t) \:{\rm d}t\\\\
&=e \:\Gamma(0,1)-e\: \Gamma(0,\ln 2)-\ln \ln 2\\\\
&=0.2055181967826824478991032883288\ldots
\end{align}
$$ 
where we have used the [Euler incomplete $\Gamma(0,\cdot)$ function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2#E2).

Comment: Very nicely done (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssis Thank you.

Comment: Maple is able to compute this integral and the result is                                                                $$-ln(ln(2))-2Ei(1,ln(2))+exp(1)Ei(1,1)$$